# stop movieclip when it reaches specific frame

Tags: flash-cs5

I have created a movieclip which have 120 frames.

Now i have used multiple instances of this movieclip on stage.

I want each movieclip to stop when it reaches a particular frame. (frame number is different for all instances)

i tried following code

```
if (char_1.currentFrame == 36) {char_1.stop();}
```

but it's not working. i tried to trace the current frame and it's always showing 1.

```
trace(char_1.currentFrame);
```

Any solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
// root
var allMCs:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
allMCs[char_1] = 32;  // frame on which to stop char_1
allMCs[char_2] = 12;  // frame on which to stop char_2
allMCs[char_3] = 47;  // frame on which to stop char_3
// ... add more

// add ENTER_FRAME listener
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(evt:Event):void
{
    // loop through all MCs and check their frame
    for (var mc:MovieClip in allMCs)
    {
        trace(mc + " frame: " + mc.currentFrame);
        if (mc.currentFrame == allMCs[mc])
        {
            mc.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

if the traces still state that the `currentFrame` is 1, make sure to do a `play();` in every MC you use.